# Creating save button that saves mxd as previous version

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-10.4

I'm running 10.4 right now and I was wondering if there's a way to create a save button add-in that would save the mxd as 10.2? I know there's the arcpy command saveACopy but I imagine that would keep the 10.4 version of the mxd and just create a copy of the mxd in 10.2. I was hoping to just make a button that would make the original mxd 10.2, and save it as 10.2 every time I used it. I don't want to create a whole bunch of mxds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is one i have considered for a while. The issue is the way Arc "creates a copy" in the older version. It must keep the later version mxd open to create the copy. When you open and save the new copy in 10.4 it will revert to a 10.4 version again.

So...I see three potential solutions.

1. Using the "customize" window drag the "saveacopy" tool into your toolbar and manually save a copy each instance deleting the 10.4 version each time. Not ideal.
2. The second. You use the Python "saveacopy" command as a standalone script, running outside of your Arc session. The script will be hard coded to search a directory for mxds and open each one and save the copy, deleting the 10.4 version on success. This link contains the code to use: [ESRI Support: Batching the SaveAs Command](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011219)
3. Thirdly, you could create an ESRI Add-in using .Net to run in ArcCatalog, which does the same thing as the Python script. You could build in options to handle folder or mxd selection and what to do with the document when the process has been completed.

Instead of deleting the mxd it could move it to a 10.4 folder...keeping your drives neat.

Comment: I might try the second solution of yours. It's unfortunate they don't have something easier. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This link contains a Tool to do exactly what is done in Step 2...minus the deleting of the old mxd: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011219